# Function returning <error-type> instead of the intended raw pointer to a template class in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I am having trouble using the `first_` variable in my template class (shown below).

```
template<typename T> class enable_movable_ptr {
public:
    //default constructor
    enable_movable_ptr() : ptr_(nullptr) {};
    enable_movable_ptr(T* p) : ptr_(p) {};

    //...
    //other constructors and operators
    //...

    T* get() {return ptr_; };
    movable_ptr<T>* First() { return first_; };
private:
    T* ptr_;
    movable_ptr<T>* first_ = nullptr;
};

template<typename T> class movable_ptr {
public:
    //Parameterless constructor
    movable_ptr() : trg_(nullptr) {};

    //Constructor from T*
    movable_ptr(T* p) : trg_(p) { add_to_tracked(this); };

    //...
    //other constructors and operators
    //...

    //access to variables
    enable_movable_ptr<T>* get() {return trg_; };
    movable_ptr<T>* Next(enable_movable_ptr<T>& p) {return next_; };
    movable_ptr<T>* Previous(enable_movable_ptr<T>& p) {return prev_; };

    //get_movable
    movable_ptr<T>* get_movable(enable_movable_ptr<T>& p) {};
private:
    enable_movable_ptr<T>* trg_;
    movable_ptr<T>* next_ = nullptr;
    movable_ptr<T>* prev_ = nullptr;
};

template<typename T> movable_ptr<T> get_movable(enable_movable_ptr<T>& p){
    if (p.First() != nullptr)
    {}
};
```

The problem is, the returned `first_` is of the `<error-type>` type (that's what it shows if I mouse over any `first_` or `First()` in the code, except for the declaration in VS2019), instead of the expected `movable_ptr<T>*`. However, if I mouse over the declaration of `first_`, it shows the correct `movable_ptr<T>*` type.

From my point of view it seems as if the compiler has the memory of a goldfish, and forgets what the type is even while still within the same class definition. That is most likely not the case, and I suspect there is something I might have done wrong which causes this.

Any ideas on where I went wrong, or how to solve the problem?

Comment: You seem to put an awfully big amount of trust into what your IDE shows you when you "mouse over" something. Don't. Consider it a "helpful hint/guess" at best.

Comment: If this is the exact order of your code then `movable_ptr` is just not yet known when you declare `template<typename T> class enable_movable_ptr`. The memory of a compiler is fine but it reads from top to down. ;-)

Comment: Yep, now I see that clearly. Forgetting the basics while dealing with details can lead to problems, who would've guessed :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just forward declare `movable_ptr` before defining `enable_movable_ptr`.

```
template<typename T> class movable_ptr;
```

Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know that `movable_ptr` is even a thing that *might* exist.

Also, it's better to not rely on external tooling, such as your IDE, to tell you what is wrong with the code. Let the compiler do that; it very likely knows much more about your code.

Here's where the issue actually comes from (I've removed all the code that is irrelevant to your particular issue)

```
// you need to forward declare
template <typename T> struct movable_ptr;

template <typename T> struct enable_movable_ptr {
  movable_ptr<T>* first_ = nullptr;  // else compiler won't know what movable_ptr is
};

template <typename T> struct movable_ptr {  
  enable_movable_ptr<T>* trg_;
};
```

Here's a link to the [mcve](https://godbolt.org/z/TtK2h3).

Comment: @Scheff that's a good idea, thanks. I added your example, but slightly modified.